# PyQGIS with edit(lyr) addFeature command returns FALSE

Tags: pyqgis

I'm using some code as per other threads to simply add a new feature to a new table, inside QGIS. The destination and source are both geopackages.

```
with edit(lyr):
    trans = lyr.addFeature(a_rec)
```

`a_rec` is simply a copy of a record from the result of a query.

I've tried performing this in the console as well and the result of trans is always `False`.
I can manually perform these operations using the QGIS GUI. In this instance, the destination table is - for this example - exactly the same as the source table (so its field list and data types are the same and the coordinate system is the same - it's a copy of the source table!).

Unfortunately, there is no further detail on the transaction that occurs (ie: No traceback). So I'm currently a bit baffled as to what to investigate further.

I have also attempted to run the transaction in the following code

```
lyr.startEditing()
trans = lyr.addFeature(a_rec)
lyr.stopEditing()
```

However, the `trans` is still `False` and nothing gets written.

Comment: Could you add the query?

Comment: It might be because it is using the same feature `id`, which must be unique. Try using `a_rec.setId(new_id)` to an `id` that does not yet exist.

Comment: @Matt - you were right. The source and destinations are Geopackages. When setting up a_rec, the 'fid' value was being copied over. This upset the addFeature method. i got around it slightly different though, I just set it to NULL, and then upon insert, it gets created to a new value. Do you want to put your comment as the answer? ill accept it with some minor edits to include gpkg and NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely because the feature `fid` is not unique as it is being copied from the orignal feature. Set the `fid` to `NULL` before inserting the feature into the layer.